# Spring : Spring scheduler with fixed-rate param work incorrectly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Someone had such that the spring scheduler starts much more often than indicated in the settings fixed-rate param ?

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler"> 
<task:scheduled ref="beanB" method="methodB" fixed-rate="5000" initial-delay="1000"/>
```

Comment: Given your settings, methodB should be invoked every 5 seconds after an initial 1 second delay. Can you give more detail about the behaviour you are seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [Official Spring Documentation on Task Execution and Scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) :

1. `fixed-rate` **refers to how often the method should be executed regardless of how long any previous execution takes.**
2. `fixed-delay` **refers to how many milliseconds to wait/hold after each task has completed its execution.**
3. `initial-delay` **refers to how many milliseconds to wait/hold before the first method is executed.**

Example :

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="beanB" method="methodB" fixed-delay="2000" fixed-rate="5000" initial-delay="1000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

So, add `fixed-delay` in the existing scheduler.

Comment: Wow.. I skip this moment with fixed-delay param. I will try! Thanks!

Comment: If it works, please verify this as the accepted answer. :)